# How I can use the Detail Disclosure Button whith Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, disclosure

I try to use the Detail Disclosure Button with the Storyboard, but when I build a segue from Disclosure Button to a new View it works only, when I press the table cell and not, when I press the Detail Disclosure Button.

What must I do?

Thanks,

Bernhard

Comment: Are you implementing said segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong but I have found that it needs to be implemented through UITableDelegate code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do a segue based on the indexPath or do any setup later in prepareForSegue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
}
```

And then in your `prepareForSegue`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]){

        NSIndexPath * indexPath =  self.sequenceTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
       // do some prep based on indexPath, if needed

     }
}
```

Comment: I can verify this works, did it yesterday. Make sure you link the segue from controller a to controller b, i.e. from master to detail, though and not from the cell.

Answer (score 0):

skinnyTOD's answer is fine. But I don't know why self.sequenceTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow; returns nil(0x0000000), I have to use a property to save the selectedRow in accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do a segue based on the indexPath or do any setup later in prepareForSegue
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
        // use self.selectedRow here
    }
}
```